# How to pass a rule from configparser to BeatifulfulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, configparser

There is a method that processes soup:

```
def get_title(self):
    # print(self.get_page)
    # print(self.title_rule)
    # print(self.get_page.find(self.title_rule))
    title = self.get_page.find(self.title_rule).text
    return textwrap.fill(title, width=79)
```

the self.get_page print the page -  its ok:

```
@property
def get_page(self):
    page = requests.get(self.url)
    page.encoding = self.encode
    return BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

the self.title_rule get the rule from config.ini:

```
$print(self.title_rule)
'h1', {'class': 'title'}

[pravda.ru]
title = 'h1', {'class': 'title'}

def get_rule(self):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(path)
    title_rule = config.get(self.site_name, "title")
    return title_rule
```

But when i try:

```
print(self.get_page.find(self.title_rule))
None
```

If i try:

```
print(self.get_page.find('h1', {'class': 'title'}))
```

or

```
rule = 'h1', {'class': 'title'}
print(self.get_page.find(rule))
```

its OK!

I think it is because a string comes from the configuration file.

such as: `rule = "'h1', {'class': 'title'}", self.title_rule = "'h1', {'class': 'title'}"`

Please, help me, get from config

```
self.title_rule = 'h1', {'class': 'title'}
```

without ("), not string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this line:

```
print(self.get_page.find(self.title_rule))
```

is that self.title_rule hasn't been set up, all you seem to have is a local variable title_rule, in the class method get_title_rule and a private class variable called 'title'. So I suggest you use

```
print(self.get_page().find(self.get_title_rule()))
```

note the brackets after get_page as well!